# Getting active click working on Components in EmberJS?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a JSON structure that I'm passing into a Toolbar to try out dynamic compartmentalization in EmberJS. It looks like this:

```
{
    draggable: true,
    buttons: [
      {label: "Portrait", action="vertical"},
      {label: "Landscape", action="horizontal"}
    ]
}
```

I'm using it in a picture viewer that turns a photo vertically and horizontally. Because it's supposed to be a reusable toolbar for other parts of the application, I made it a Component and hooked the click event to the parent controller so it would turn the picture on click. I wanted the button to also get the active class like it does in other examples, but I think that's not working because of the embedded nature of the buttons. How do I get the button that gets clicked to get the active class so I can add css to it?

I tried setting an isActive property in each of the button objects in the model when init gets called and then setting that as true via the action function but I couldn't get observables to work with nested data structures. Do I have to make each button a separate component or can I avoid that?

Thanks for the help.

**Templates**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="photo-gallery">
    <div id="PictureApp"></div>
    {{#if toolbar}}
        {{ui-toolbar options=toolbar buttonClicked="changeOrientation"}}
    {{/if}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/ui-toolbar">
    {{title}}
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="toolbar draggable">
            {{#if draggable}}
            <div class="header draggable-handle"></div>
            {{/if}}
            <ul>
                {{#each buttons}}
                    <li{{action "clicked" this}}>{{label}}</li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

**JS**

```
App.UiToolbarComponent = App.Component.extend({
    actions: {
        clicked: function(context){
            console.log(context);
            this.sendAction("buttonClicked", context.action);

        }
    },
    didInsertElement: function(){
        if(this.get("draggable")) {
            this.$(".draggable").draggable({handle: ".draggable-handle"});
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're on the right track. I think you could set the active property property on the button, however, you still need to set clear the `active` flag on any other button.

Inside the clicked action:

```
   clicked: function(context){
     console.log(context);
     this.buttons.setEach('active', false);
     context.set('active', true)
     this.sendAction("buttonClicked", context.action);
   }
```

Then on your template you can bind the class:

```
            {{#each buttons}}
                <li {{bind-attr class=active}} {{action "clicked" this}}>{{label}}</li>
            {{/each}}
```

Comment: I like the setEach method. Thanks.